# Apply default built-in theme in VBA to PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How do I apply the built-in theme to a PowerPoint presentation without using file path?  I need this to be compatible with Mac so I can't really use hard path.  Can I just use the built-in theme name like 'Angel", "Apax", etc?  This is what I currently have

```
Application.ActivePresentation.ApplyTemplate "c:\folder_path\theme_name.pot"
```

I don't need to use custom theme, the built-in theme that came with Office will suffice.

Comment: No, you need a full path to the template file in order to applly it. There are no built-in themes other than the default one you get when creating a new presentation. The others are all files, but the directory is fairly predictable; look at where PPT points you when you choose to save a presentation as POT/POTX.  That's where it'll always look by default for template files.

Comment: So there is no way to use the default themes?  Like is there a list of loaded themes that I can just use?

Comment: "Default themes" is sort of meaningless. The set of themes installed with Office varies from version to version and even from installation to installation.  There may some subset of themes you can always count on for a given version but you'd still need to call them up by filename.